# Set Animation For Expandable List down/up

Tags: android, list, animation, expandable

How I can set animation(expand/collapse) for expandable list whit use customize adapter that extend BaseExpandableListAdapter?

Update:
Like This : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7rcFRKvpyY

Comment: Can you improve your question? Post some code or examples of what you are trying to do?

Comment: yes i need like this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=J7rcFRKvpyY

Answer (score 0):

You need to include this in the layout file, in the parent of your list

```
android:animateLayoutChanges="true"
```

Then something like this in onCreate() in your activity.

```
    LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.list_container);
    LayoutTransition t = layout.getLayoutTransition();
    t.setDuration(200);            // 200ms
    layout.setLayoutTransition(t);
```

You can learn more about using LayoutTransition [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/LayoutTransition.html)

Comment: Sorry that didn't help you out.  Did you notice the GitHub link in the video description? [link](https://github.com/idunnololz/AnimatedExpandableListView)